# Open every files type in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm developping a messaging app allowing user to add attachments to their messages.

Is there a way to open every files type ? Maybe like `Intent` in Android ? Or in `WebView` ?

Types are docx, pdf, png, jpg, mov, xls, zip, mp3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is an apple framework that can allow the user to view local files of these types.

```
QLPreviewController
```

This opens most local documents / media files.

To use you have to import `QuickLook`